# In Joomla, SEF Url Conversion query not get View and layout

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, sef

I Newly to develop a Component with SEF Feature.

I Pass Following query for route.php

```
JRoute::_('index.php?com_example&view=profile&layout=item_interestonme&id='.$itemval["profile_id"]);
```

In route.php,

```
$query display Array ( [Itemid] => 114 [option] => com_example )
```

Only. view, layout, id not display. how to fix this issue.

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

There is a preprocess method in the Router-interface, defined like this:

```
 /**
 * Prepare-method for URLs
 * This method is meant to validate and complete the URL parameters.
 * For example it can add the Itemid or set a language parameter.
 * This method is executed on each URL, regardless of SEF mode switched
 * on or not.
 *
 * @param   array  $query  An associative array of URL arguments
 *
 * @return  array  The URL arguments to use to assemble the subsequent URL.
 *
 * @since   3.3
 */
public function preprocess($query);
```

You could try to override this in route.php. Perhaps the display-parameter is stripped from the query in the default implementation?